# How to have systems in systems in tikz-uml

Tags: tikz-uml

I'm using the `tikz-uml` package and attempting to create a use case diagram, where I have a system in another system, like so:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgfopts}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{umlsystem} [x=0, y=0] {System 1}
        \begin{umlsystem} [x=0.1, y=-1] {System 2}

        \end{umlsystem} 
    \end{umlsystem}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output ends up like this:
[image: Actual outout]

This is how i would like to have it look:
[image: Prefered output]

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please show us what you have attempted so far and add a minimal working example  [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` (including only relevant packages). So that the people here don't need to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the second system after the first one, and inside the first one add

```
\tikzset{every node/.append style={inner xsep=12ex,inner ysep=3em}}
```

Basically a `system` without any `\umlusecase` is just an empty node with the settings `inner xsep=10ex, inner ysep=1em`. The `tikzset` line overrides that setting, making the node a little bit bigger. You can then place the second system, which will have the default size, on top.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{umlsystem}{System 1}
    \tikzset{every node/.append style={inner xsep=12ex,inner ysep=3em}}
    \end{umlsystem}
    \begin{umlsystem}[y=0.2]{System 2}
    \end{umlsystem} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```